# Connecting Tableau to Teradata with Custom SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2, tableau-api, teradata-sql-assistant

**EDIT**: Even if I try removing that 'AS' everywhere, I continue getting errors about things that seem like normal SQL commands. If I remove the 'AS', the next error I get is:

> [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0199N The use of the reserved word "CAST"
> following "" is not valid. Expected tokens may include: ", )".
> SQLSTATE=42601

**Question**:
I am trying to connect to Teradata with a Custom SQL Query, and while it is running perfectly in Teradata SQL Assistant, I keep getting errors when trying to run it in Tableau.

One of the errors looks like this, but even if I try to change something, a similar error will come up:

> [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0199N The use of the reserved word "AS"
> following "" is not valid. Expected tokens may include: "JOIN CROSS
> INNER LEFT RIGHT FULL (". SQLSTATE=42601

Here is the query (sorry, it's long):

```
WITH RQSTS AS(

select CAST( M.RQST_ID AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MASTER_RQST_ID,

M.RQST_TYP_CD

FROM PRTHD.HOST_RQST AS M --MASTER

WHERE M.MSTR_RQST_ID IS NULL

  AND M.crt_user_id='SXB8NBS'

  AND M.OCYC_SOQ_RSN_CD = 170

  AND date(M.CRT_TS) >= CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAY

),

 

RQST_TYPE AS(

select R.MASTER_RQST_ID AS RQST_ID, 

NRT.TYP_DESC AS HOST_TYPE

FROM RQSTS AS R

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.N_HOST_RQST_TYP AS NRT     

ON R.RQST_TYP_CD = NRT.RQST_TYP_CD

GROUP BY R.MASTER_RQST_ID, NRT.TYP_DESC

),

 

PO_DETAILS AS(

select A.* 

FROM (

  SELECT distinct PRTHD.BYO_PO.DSVC_TYP_CD,

  RT.RQST_ID,

  RT.HOST_TYPE,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO.PO_CMT_TXT,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO.BYO_NBR,

  CASE WHEN PRTHD.BYO_PO.DSVC_TYP_CD = 2 THEN RIGHT('00'||PRTHD.BYO_PO.BYO_NBR,2) 

     ELSE RIGHT('00'|| PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.LOC_NBR,2) END

  || PRTHD.BYO_PO.acct_po_typ_cd || RIGHT('00000'||PRTHD.BYO_PO.PO_CTRL_NBR,5) AS PO,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO.ORD_REF_NBR,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_NBR,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.LOC_NBR,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.SKU_NBR,

  CAST(PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ORD_QTY AS INTEGER) AS ORD_QTY,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO.CRT_DT,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO.PO_CTRL_NBR,

  M.MVNDR_NM,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO.MVNDR_NBR,

  PRTHD.BYO_PO.OCYC_SOQ_RSN_CD AS RSN_CD

FROM ((PRTHD.BYO_PO AS BP INNER JOIN PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU

  ON (PRTHD.BYO_PO.ORD_SEQ_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ORD_SEQ_NBR)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO.PO_CTRL_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.PO_CTRL_NBR)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO.ACCT_PO_TYP_CD = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ACCT_PO_TYP_CD)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO.MKT_DC_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_NBR)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO.MKT_DC_IND = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_IND)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO.BYO_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.BYO_NBR))

INNER JOIN PRTHD.SKU 

  ON PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.SKU_NBR = PRTHD.SKU.SKU_NBR)

INNER JOIN PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU 

  ON (PRTHD.SKU.SKU_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.SKU_NBR)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.BYO_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.BYO_NBR) 

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_IND = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.MKT_DC_IND)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.MKT_DC_NBR)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ACCT_PO_TYP_CD = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.ACCT_PO_TYP_CD)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.PO_CTRL_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.PO_CTRL_NBR)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ORD_SEQ_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.ORD_SEQ_NBR)

  AND (PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.PO_LINE_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.PO_LINE_NBR)

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MVNDR AS M

  ON M.MVNDR_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO.MVNDR_NBR

INNER JOIN RQST_TYPE AS RT

  ON TRIM(SUBSTR(BP.PO_CMT_TXT,6,11)) = RT.RQST_ID

) AS A)

 

Select P.RQST_ID,

P.DSVC_TYP_CD,

CASE WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD =1 THEN 'DTS'

   WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD =2 THEN 'RDC AGG'

   WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD =3 THEN 'RDCX'

   END AS DSVC_TYP_DESC ,

CASE WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD =2 AND S.STR_NBR IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'

   ELSE 'N' END AS RDC_AGG_PEG_FLG,

CASE WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD =2 AND S.STR_NBR IS NOT NULL THEN P.ORD_REF_NBR

   ELSE P.PO END AS PO_NBR,

P.BYO_NBR,

P.PO_CTRL_NBR,

P.CRT_DT,

P.HOST_TYPE,

P.MVNDR_NBR,

P.MVNDR_NM,

CASE WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD =2 AND S.STR_NBR IS NOT NULL THEN AR.MKT_DC_NBR 

   ELSE P.MKT_DC_NBR END AS MKT_DC_NBR,

P.LOC_NBR,

COALESCE(SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR || '-' || D.SHRT_DEPT_NM,'') AS DEPT,

COALESCE(SKU.MER_CLASS_NBR || '-' || MC.SHRT_CLASS_DESC,'') AS CLASS,

COALESCE(SKU.MER_SUB_CLASS_NBR || '-' || MSC.SHRT_SUBCLASS_DESC,'') AS SUB_CLASS,

P.SKU_NBR,

P.ORD_QTY,

COALESCE(SD.AVG_DC_LCOST_AMT*COALESCE(P.ORD_QTY,0),

MSM.CURR_COST_AMT*COALESCE(P.ORD_QTY,0)) AS TOTAL_COST,

SD.AVG_DC_LCOST_AMT AS SD_COST,

MSM.CURR_COST_AMT AS STR_CURR_COST,

MSD.CURR_COST_AMT AS DC_CURR_COST,

P.PO_CMT_TXT,

P.RSN_CD

FROM PO_DETAILS AS P

--SKU HIERARCHY INFO

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.SKU  AS SKU                

  ON SKU.SKU_NBR = P.SKU_NBR

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.DEPT AS D                    

  ON SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR = D.DEPT_NBR

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MER_CLASS AS MC           

  ON MC.MER_DEPT_NBR= SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR 

  AND MC.MER_CLASS_NBR = SKU.MER_CLASS_NBR

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MER_SUB_CLASS AS MSC    

  ON MSC.MER_DEPT_NBR= SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR 

  AND MSC.MER_CLASS_NBR = SKU.MER_CLASS_NBR 

  AND MSC.MER_SUB_CLASS_NBR = SKU.MER_SUB_CLASS_NBR

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MVNDR_SKU_DC AS MSD     

  ON MSD.MVNDR_NBR = P.MVNDR_NBR 

  AND MSD.SKU_NBR = P.SKU_NBR 

  AND MSD.DC_NBR = P.LOC_NBR

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.STR AS S                  

  ON S.STR_NBR = P.LOC_NBR

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.SKU_DC AS SD               

  ON SD.DC_NBR=P.MKT_DC_NBR 

  AND SD.SKU_NBR=P.SKU_NBR

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MVNDR_SKU_MKT AS MSM    

  ON MSM.MVNDR_NBR = P.MVNDR_NBR 

  AND MSM.SKU_NBR = P.SKU_NBR 

  AND MSM.MKT_NBR = S.MKT_NBR

LEFT JOIN PRTHD.AGG_RQST AS AR 

  ON AR.PO_NBR = P.ORD_REF_NBR 

  AND P.MVNDR_NBR = AR.MVNDR_NBR 

  AND SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR = AR.MER_DEPT_NBR

  AND AR.ORD_DT >= P.CRT_DT
```

Can anyone help me figure out what might be going wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: This is DB2 syntax, you might be using Teradata's SQL Assistant, but you connect to DB2, not Teradata.

Comment: Please, provide `CREATE TABLE` statements for all participating tables. It's not possible to check your query otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the `AS`:

```
WITH RQSTS (
    select CT(M.RQST_ID  VARCHAR(20))  MTER_RQST_ID,
        M.RQST_TYP_CD
    FROM PRTHD.HOST_RQST  M --MTER
    WHERE M.MSTR_RQST_ID IS NULL
        AND M.crt_user_id = 'SXB8NBS'
        AND M.OCYC_SOQ_RSN_CD = 170
        AND date(M.CRT_TS) >= CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAY
),
RQST_TYPE (
    select R.MTER_RQST_ID  RQST_ID,
        NRT.TYP_DESC  HOST_TYPE
    FROM RQSTS  R
        LEFT JOIN PRTHD.N_HOST_RQST_TYP  NRT ON R.RQST_TYP_CD = NRT.RQST_TYP_CD
    GROUP BY R.MTER_RQST_ID,
        NRT.TYP_DESC
),
PO_DETAILS (
    select A.*
    FROM (
            SELECT distinct PRTHD.BYO_PO.DSVC_TYP_CD,
                RT.RQST_ID,
                RT.HOST_TYPE,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO.PO_CMT_TXT,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO.BYO_NBR,
                CE
                    WHEN PRTHD.BYO_PO.DSVC_TYP_CD = 2 THEN RIGHT('00' || PRTHD.BYO_PO.BYO_NBR, 2)
                    ELSE RIGHT('00' || PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.LOC_NBR, 2)
                END || PRTHD.BYO_PO.acct_po_typ_cd || RIGHT('00000' || PRTHD.BYO_PO.PO_CTRL_NBR, 5)  PO,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO.ORD_REF_NBR,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_NBR,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.LOC_NBR,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.SKU_NBR,
                CT(PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ORD_QTY  INTEGER)  ORD_QTY,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO.CRT_DT,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO.PO_CTRL_NBR,
                M.MVNDR_NM,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO.MVNDR_NBR,
                PRTHD.BYO_PO.OCYC_SOQ_RSN_CD  RSN_CD
            FROM (
                    (
                        PRTHD.BYO_PO  BP
                        INNER JOIN PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU ON (
                            PRTHD.BYO_PO.ORD_SEQ_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ORD_SEQ_NBR
                        )
                        AND (
                            PRTHD.BYO_PO.PO_CTRL_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.PO_CTRL_NBR
                        )
                        AND (
                            PRTHD.BYO_PO.ACCT_PO_TYP_CD = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ACCT_PO_TYP_CD
                        )
                        AND (
                            PRTHD.BYO_PO.MKT_DC_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_NBR
                        )
                        AND (
                            PRTHD.BYO_PO.MKT_DC_IND = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_IND
                        )
                        AND (
                            PRTHD.BYO_PO.BYO_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.BYO_NBR
                        )
                    )
                    INNER JOIN PRTHD.SKU ON PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.SKU_NBR = PRTHD.SKU.SKU_NBR
                )
                INNER JOIN PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU ON (PRTHD.SKU.SKU_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.SKU_NBR)
                AND (
                    PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.BYO_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.BYO_NBR
                )
                AND (
                    PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_IND = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.MKT_DC_IND
                )
                AND (
                    PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.MKT_DC_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.MKT_DC_NBR
                )
                AND (
                    PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ACCT_PO_TYP_CD = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.ACCT_PO_TYP_CD
                )
                AND (
                    PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.PO_CTRL_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.PO_CTRL_NBR
                )
                AND (
                    PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.ORD_SEQ_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.ORD_SEQ_NBR
                )
                AND (
                    PRTHD.BYO_PO_LOC_SKU.PO_LINE_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO_SKU.PO_LINE_NBR
                )
                LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MVNDR  M ON M.MVNDR_NBR = PRTHD.BYO_PO.MVNDR_NBR
                INNER JOIN RQST_TYPE  RT ON TRIM(SUBSTR(BP.PO_CMT_TXT, 6, 11)) = RT.RQST_ID
        )  A
)
Select P.RQST_ID,
    P.DSVC_TYP_CD,
    CE
        WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD = 1 THEN 'DTS'
        WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD = 2 THEN 'RDC AGG'
        WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD = 3 THEN 'RDCX'
    END  DSVC_TYP_DESC,
    CE
        WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD = 2
        AND S.STR_NBR IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END  RDC_AGG_PEG_FLG,
    CE
        WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD = 2
        AND S.STR_NBR IS NOT NULL THEN P.ORD_REF_NBR
        ELSE P.PO
    END  PO_NBR,
    P.BYO_NBR,
    P.PO_CTRL_NBR,
    P.CRT_DT,
    P.HOST_TYPE,
    P.MVNDR_NBR,
    P.MVNDR_NM,
    CE
        WHEN P.DSVC_TYP_CD = 2
        AND S.STR_NBR IS NOT NULL THEN AR.MKT_DC_NBR
        ELSE P.MKT_DC_NBR
    END  MKT_DC_NBR,
    P.LOC_NBR,
    COALESCE(SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR || '-' || D.SHRT_DEPT_NM, '')  DEPT,
    COALESCE(
        SKU.MER_CLS_NBR || '-' || MC.SHRT_CLS_DESC,
        ''
    )  CLS,
    COALESCE(
        SKU.MER_SUB_CLS_NBR || '-' || MSC.SHRT_SUBCLS_DESC,
        ''
    )  SUB_CLS,
    P.SKU_NBR,
    P.ORD_QTY,
    COALESCE(
        SD.AVG_DC_LCOST_AMT * COALESCE(P.ORD_QTY, 0),
        MSM.CURR_COST_AMT * COALESCE(P.ORD_QTY, 0)
    )  TOTAL_COST,
    SD.AVG_DC_LCOST_AMT  SD_COST,
    MSM.CURR_COST_AMT  STR_CURR_COST,
    MSD.CURR_COST_AMT  DC_CURR_COST,
    P.PO_CMT_TXT,
    P.RSN_CD
FROM PO_DETAILS  P --SKU HIERARCHY INFO
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.SKU  SKU ON SKU.SKU_NBR = P.SKU_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.DEPT  D ON SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR = D.DEPT_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MER_CLS  MC ON MC.MER_DEPT_NBR = SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR
    AND MC.MER_CLS_NBR = SKU.MER_CLS_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MER_SUB_CLS  MSC ON MSC.MER_DEPT_NBR = SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR
    AND MSC.MER_CLS_NBR = SKU.MER_CLS_NBR
    AND MSC.MER_SUB_CLS_NBR = SKU.MER_SUB_CLS_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MVNDR_SKU_DC  MSD ON MSD.MVNDR_NBR = P.MVNDR_NBR
    AND MSD.SKU_NBR = P.SKU_NBR
    AND MSD.DC_NBR = P.LOC_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.STR  S ON S.STR_NBR = P.LOC_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.SKU_DC  SD ON SD.DC_NBR = P.MKT_DC_NBR
    AND SD.SKU_NBR = P.SKU_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.MVNDR_SKU_MKT  MSM ON MSM.MVNDR_NBR = P.MVNDR_NBR
    AND MSM.SKU_NBR = P.SKU_NBR
    AND MSM.MKT_NBR = S.MKT_NBR
    LEFT JOIN PRTHD.AGG_RQST  AR ON AR.PO_NBR = P.ORD_REF_NBR
    AND P.MVNDR_NBR = AR.MVNDR_NBR
    AND SKU.MER_DEPT_NBR = AR.MER_DEPT_NBR
    AND AR.ORD_DT >= P.CRT_DT
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do that, I just get another error :(
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0199N The use of the reserved word "CAST" following "" is not valid. Expected tokens may include: ", )". SQLSTATE=42601